# In Chartist, how do I add specific options to specific charts?

Tags: javascript, chartist.js

I have a page with several charts on it, using [Chartist](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js). I want to have both **global** options and **individual** options for each chart.

```
var barChartOptions = {
    reverseData: true,
    horizontalBars: true,
}

new Chartist.Bar('#chart1', {
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    series: [[100, 120, 180, 200]]
},barChartOptions
  // HOW DO I ADD SPECIFIC OPTIONS?!
                );

new Chartist.Bar('#chart2', {
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    series: [[120, 90, 150, 100]]
},barChartOptions);

new Chartist.Bar('#chart3', {
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    series: [[180, 190, 90, 110]]
},barChartOptions);
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yosefw/pddpcg97/1/) showcasing my problem.

Note: I'm a JavaScript n00b, so I might be missing something very basic here.

Comment: The JSFiddle doesn't link to JSFiddle but rather to Chartist. Will be happy to help, if you fix the link.

Comment: @arikfr - oops! It's fixed now, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use jQuery or Underscore.js, you can use the `extend` ([jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/), [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#extend)) function to merge two objects, so you can do:

```
var barChartOptions = {
  reverseData: true,
  horizontalBars: true,
}

new Chartist.Bar('#chart1', {
  labels: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  series: [[100, 120, 180, 200]]
},_.extend({/*specific options*/}, barChartOptions));
```

This way the object that will be passed to `Chartist.Bar` is your specific options merged with the global `barChartOptions`.

Comment: Nice! And what if I want to overwrite some of the global options? Will that be possible with this method as well?

Comment: Then change it like so: `_.extend({}, barChartOptions, {/*specific options*/}`. This will create a new object, and merge the other two on top of it, overriding global options with specific ones. The first `{}` is important, otherwise you will overwrite the `barChartOptions` object everytime.